# Matlab Arduino Multi Byte Read

Tags: arduino-uno, matlab

I'm using Matlab to communicate with a custom AD7746 board through an Arduino UNO. The data sheet mentions that 
***"In continuous conversion mode, the address pointers’ autoincrementer should be used for reading a conversion result. 
That means, the three data bytes should be read using one 
multibyte read transaction rather than three separate single byte 
transactions"***
I'm not sure how I can go about implementing this using MATLAB's Arduino support package.
Would anyone have an Idea about this?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far. Have you read data from the sensor yet?

Comment: I think I figured it out.
Matlab's Arduino package has a "read" command which lets you read data from an I2C device and allows you to specify the number of bytes.
I'm just testing it to make sure that I got it right